# dom not loading when referencing an external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am referencing the jQuery library, in a master page like so:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" />
```

The page loads and I am presented with a blank screen. If I take a look at the source the hmtl code is present, but the browser is simply not displaying any of the elements.

I have tried co-locating the master and the js fail to no avail.

Opening the FF with firebug I get the following error :

Failed to load source for: http://localhost:50417/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js , yet navigating to this url I am able to load the js.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not valid to use the `/>` shortcut for `script tags`. It must look like

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, so minor yet so maddening.

Comment: @Mule See [Why Don't Self Closing Script Tags Work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) for additional info